# Example implementation of 'TryParse' or 'TryGetValue'

Tags: c#, design-patterns

Can you give me an example of implementation of .NET 'try' pattern?

**Edit:**

I don't mean a "try-catch" statement, I mean a try patterns, like those used in `TryParse()`, and `TryGetObjectByKey()` methods.

Most specifically what to do with raised exceptions in custom 'try' pattern methods. Should I log it, should I ignore It. Does' anybody know what is the practice with those methods?

Comment: If you mean the language feature, then quid pro quo: please give me an example of your having attempted to read the documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yd65esw(VS.80).aspx

Comment: You mean the [ `try`/`catch` statement? ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yd65esw.aspx)

Comment: next question: Please explain the void pattern?

Comment: Wondering what else people will call a 'pattern'…

Comment: I understand what you are saying, check out the mscorlib for .NET, all of the TryParse methods are there on the base types.  I assume this would be a good pattern?

https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/mscorlib/shared/System/Int32.cs

https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/da8b7181dbe362fbfe64c7ef72ff3a4a7db68f24/src/mscorlib/src/System/Number.cs

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Here is an example of *using* a TryXxx method:

```
string s = Console.ReadLine();
int x;
if (int.TryParse(s, out x))
{
    Console.WriteLine("You entered the valid integer {0}", x);
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Invalid input!");
}
```

Here is an example of *defining* the method:

```
bool TryParse(string s, out int x)  // out parameter for result
{
    if (!allCharactersAreValid(s))
    {
        x = 0;
        return false;
    }

    // More checks...
    // Parse the string...

    x = 42;
    return true;
}
```

**Exception handling**

> Most specificly what to do with rised exceptions in custom 'try' pattern methods

Your method probably should avoid throwing any exceptions - if your user wanted exceptions they would use the non-Try version. You should therefore try to avoid calling methods which can throw when implementing your TryXxx. However some exceptions are unavoidable and could be thrown out of your control - for example `OutOfMemoryException`, `StackOverflowException`, etc... There is nothing you can do about this and you should not try to catch these exceptions, just let them propagate to the caller. Don't swallow them, don't log them - that's the caller's responsibility.

An example of this is `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>.TryGetValue` when the key object provided to this method throws an exception when `GetHashCode` is called. Then the resulting exception is *not* caught inside the `TryGetValue` method - the caller will see the exception. This code demonstrates this happening:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class Foo
{
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Dictionary<object, object> d = new Dictionary<object, object>();
        d["bar"] = 42;

        object s;
        Foo foo = new Foo();
        if (d.TryGetValue(foo, out s))   // results in NotImplementedException
        {
            Console.WriteLine("found");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you, but Im looking for implementation of this pattern. How to create methods like TryParse().

Comment: Indeed, too many developers assume that the `Try`-* methods are just wrappers for exception handling. That always bugs me.

Comment: I've never liked the `out` parameters, but C# still doesn't give us much to solve this problem any other way.

Comment: You can look at the mscorlib for .NET if you'd like.
https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/mscorlib/shared/System/Int32.cs

https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/da8b7181dbe362fbfe64c7ef72ff3a4a7db68f24/src/mscorlib/src/System/Number.cs

Answer (score 10):

I'd expect the implementation to look very much like the "throwing" version in each case - except where there's a "throw new FormatException" statement in the throwing version, there's "return false"... and at the end of the success path, there's an assignment to the output parameter and "return true".

To *some* extent you can simulate the throwing version from the non-throwing version (although in terms of performance you can't do the reverse) - you *can* just call `TryParse` and throw an exception if it returns false. However, that means the exception won't contain detail about *why* the parse failed.

The exact amount of code reuse you could accomplish - while still having good performance from the Try version, and detailed exceptions in the throwing version - will depend on the exact task at hand.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you mean something like `Int32.TryParse` or `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>.TryGetValue` method. Those method exists to evade  costly exception throwing, and let the caller know the failure by other means -- boolean return value in this case.

Comment: I know what they are ment for. i'm looking for implementation of such a pattern. Most specificly, what to do with rised exception.

Comment: @kofucii: There is no raised exception.  Exceptions don't just happen, some piece of code has to throw them (a very few are triggered in the CPU, but .NET still has code to handle that by throwing a .NET exception).  The implementation is pretty simple, move the return value to an "out" parameter and replace `throw new WhateverException();` with `return false;`.